# get JSON attribute value

Tags: javascript, json, attributes, trygetvalue

I have converted an XML document to JSON using Newtonsoft Library in .NET.

Some of the converted XML nodes have attributes, like this (once converted):

```
"HandID": {
  "@Room": "",
  "#text": "1"
},
```

In JavaScript the Hand is an object.

Question: how do I get the @room or the #text values in JavaScript?

Comment: @Quentin: your comment is not very useful!!! How do I find the original question if you don't provide the link? How can I say it is different, or same?

Comment: I haven't made a commnet. You're seeing a standard Stackoverflow closed question template. See also http://note.io/1aN6ZpF

Comment: The difference is that my object is a JSON one, and when I use brackets notation Hand.[text] there is an "Identifier expected" js error. Please leave my question open.

Comment: It isn't JSON after you parse it. `Hand.[text]` would give that error since it isn't the syntax shown in the duplicate question.